# Grouping and selecting the n most repeated values in each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have data for a TV game show where I have the corresponding Rounds and question categories in those rounds. I grouped the questions by round and category with the following code:

```
data.groupby(['Round']).Category.value_counts()
data.groupby(['Round']).Category.value_counts().head(n)
```

When I do the function head(n) it only shows me n observations from the first group, and I would like to get the n most repeated categories in each group

How can I find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Reversed: you can count the values first, then take the top N per "Round":

```py
df[["Round", "Category"]].value_counts().groupby(level="Round").head(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) here:

```
data.groupby('Round')['Category'].apply(lambda g: g.value_counts().head(n))
```